# knockout, set property value changes view, which doesn't raise change event

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

In my view model I update an observable's property. The property is bind to an input element.

After I change the value (from JS), the view updates.

The thing is I have other elements on the page that subscribes the the input's change event, which doesn't publish when the value is updated.

**Update (Code):**

Model:

```
var viewModel = {
    email: ko.observable()

}
```

Html:

```
<input class="form-input" data-bind="value: email" type="email" />
```

JS: (as a result of some click):

```
$('.form-input').change(function () {
   // doesn't happen
});
viewModel.email('someemail@aaa.com');
```

Comment: We gonna need some code to check what your problem is, otherwise we probably can't help!

Comment: Added code, take a look!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `change`, use the Knockout `subscribe` function. [Observables Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)

```
viewModel.email.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    // Called whenever the value is updated
    doSomethingWithNewValue(newValue);
});
```